# Tag Cleanup: [tag:combinationalcircuits]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup

There is a tag named [combinationalcircuits](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinationalcircuits) which has 12 tagged questions that seem to range from mostly combinational logic circuit type questions to one about power electronics. There was also another question just asked about resistors in parallel that used the tag (I've retagged that one).

It seems to be a rather useless tag and should probably be deleted (IMO). Doing so wouldn't leave any existing questions untagged nor make them harder to find.

---

If not deletion, perhaps renaming it to [combinational-logic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinational-logic) or something similar would make sense (and then remove the tag from a couple of existing questions). But I don't see much point in that given how few questions there are using the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and remove that tag. The existing tags [boolean-logic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boolean-logic) and [digital-logic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-logic) fill the problem space fine.

Comment: No, they really don't.  A combinatorial circuit is substantially unique in that it specifically excludes *registers*, something which can be included in the other more generic terms.  To people actually doing logic design, the distinction between combinatorial and registered implementations (or the purely combinatorial paths between registers) is  extremely important.